# How to make custom android notifications on android 11 and higher?

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am trying to make an android notification using java with the following custom features:

- The background must be one whole color.
- The notification must have a title and a subtitle.
- There must be a big countdown timer on the left (font size should be larger).

  I need this app to work on later versions of android (11 and higher). I have read that customizing notifications to that extent on newer versions of android is impossible. Using a custom layout leaves system colored borders around the notificatication and setting setColorized with the style, required to have the custom layout (Notification.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle) doesnt seem to do anything (I have set setColor).
  [my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDzZf.jpg)

I know that its possible to get the desired result since i have a few apps on my android 11 phone that have the features. One is from a VPN app another is from a navigator.
[navigator app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCwwM.jpg)
[VPN app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUEy.jpg)

Thanks for the help!